# React.js data not saving to state variable

Tags: node.js, reactjs

> I'm trying to render my workersData and ordersData however after fetching the APIs, ordersData can be rendered by using map, but when I try to render workersData it doesn't do anything. I checked with console.log and seems it does get populated with the right data but when I try to map it, it won't render it. I'm fairly new to React so any help is appreciated.

```
class FetchData extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ordersData: [],
            workersDatas: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/work_orders")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    ordersData: data.orders
            }, () => { 
                    console.log(this.state.ordersData)
                    this.state.ordersData.map(order => {
                        console.log(this.state.ordersData)
                        fetch(`https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/workers/${order.workerId}`)
                            .then(result => result.json())
                            .then(data2 => {
                                this.state.workersDatas.push(data2);
                            })
                        console.log(this.state.workersDatas)
                    })
                });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                  {this.state.workersDatas.map(order => (
                    <li>
                      hello
                    </li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<FetchData/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: have you checked the console/react dev tools?

Comment: The problem is that you are using array.push rather than react's setState method: `this.state.workersDatas.push(data2);` should be `this.setState({ workersDatas: data2 })`. Pushing to the array will not trigger a re-render.

Comment: @DerekPollard yeah checked on both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.state.workersDatas.push(data2)` is a no-no.

[Do Not Modify State Directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly). It will not re-render your components. This could be why you see the correct data in your console, but not in your component.

To make your fetch data flow easier to read, break it down into chunks instead of trying to nest multiple callbacks. Fetch the ordersData and set the state. Then use that state to fetch the workersData, and set it using the spread operator.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/work_orders")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          ordersData: data.orders
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.state.ordersData.forEach(order => {
          console.log(this.state.ordersData);
          fetch(
            `https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/workers/${order.workerId}`
          )
            .then(result=> result.json())
            .then(data2 => {
              this.setState(prevState => ({
                workersDatas: [data2, ...prevState.workersDatas]
              }));
            });
          console.log(this.state.workersDatas);
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

[image: Edit cocky-goodall-c6ok7]

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly now. I should read up on those docs

Answer (score 0):

it's because, `this.setState()` may be update the state asynchronously, so don't get the state as soon as you update the state.
this [document](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) is maybe helpful for understanding the state.